# Capturing output of .bat script in VMWare Fusion 'runProgramInGuest'

Tags: macos, batch-file, shell-script, vmware-fusion

I've recently started a new job where we run virtualized copies of Windows inside VMWare Fusion (Mac OSX is the host). Among other things, we have a few utility `.bat` files that get run regularly. I'd like to be able to run these commands from my host environment.

`vmrun` is great for this, and I've come up with something like the following:

```
vmrun -T ws -gu <user> -gp <password> runProgramInGuest <.vmx file> c:\/batch\/hello.bat
```

This executes the command, *but it does so silently*. In this case, my `hello.bat` contains the classic

```
echo "hello, world!"
```

**Question**: is there a way to capture what is sent to standard output on the Windows console and display it in my host using these commands

Comment: It occurs to me that I could also just capture the output into a file (on the GUEST) and then use additional `vmrun` commands on HOST to copy the file back and delete it from GUEST. However, this is cumbersome and would take a number of steps. Can I do it more simply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vmrun` does not provide a way to capture the output of the program running on the guest and pipe it back to you.   I suggest configuring the guest program to send the output to a file on the Host via a Shared Folder and then you can `tail` that file.

To make it more complicated, you could set up up some sort of TCP client/server connection between the guest and the host (perhaps just pipe it into SSH) but then you have to set that all up in advance.